# Update cart items quantity and price with @reduxjs/toolkit in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a cart state that holding array something like this:

```
 [[{"Id": 123, "duration": 10, "name": "Burger", "price": 10, "qty": 1, "total": "10.00"}]]
```

and this is the reducers as showing I have added to more for increase and decrease the quantity:

```
const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: "cart",
    initialState: [],
    reducers: {
        addItemToCart: (state, action) => {
            state.push(action.payload); 
        },
        removeItemFromCart: (state, action) => {
            return state.filter(i => i[0].Id !== action.payload);
        },
        ADD_QUANTITY: (state, action) => {

           // notsure how to handle here 

        },
        SUB_QUANTITY: (state, action) => {
         // notsure how to handle here 
        }
    }
})
```

and in cart screen I am doing something like this:

```
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => dispatch(ADD_QUANTITY(item[0].Id))} >
      <Ionicons name="add-circle-outline" size={22} color="#cccccc" />
   </TouchableOpacity>
```

so, once the button for add quantity pressed I want to update the cart state with new qty and new total price and same when decrease  quantity, it may sound a very easy question but I am a beginner and i cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the input array you gave you can implement the adding and subtracting of a quantity in the array like so. You would have to loop over the state using `forEach` and then check if the `Id` matches the `Id` you pass in the action payload, if it is then either increment or decrement the value.

Edit:

Looking back I realized this was wrong and also would not work on actual data. I recommend to flatten the nested array before looping over it.

```
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addItemToCart: (state, action) => {
      state.push(action.payload);
    },
    removeItemFromCart: (state, action) => {
      state.flat().filter((i) => i.Id !== action.payload);
    },
    addQuantityToItem: (state, action) => {
      state.flat().forEach((item) => {
        if (item.Id === action.payload) {
          item.qty += 1;
        }
      });
    },
    subtractQuantityFromItem: (state, action) => {
      state.flat().forEach((item) => {
        if (item.Id === action.payload) {
          item.qty -= 1;
        }
      });
    },
  },
});
```

Sample use case where you have to pass in the value of the id:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => dispatch(addQuantityToItem(id))} >
    <Ionicons name="add-circle-outline" size={22} color="#cccccc" />
</TouchableOpacity>
```